# How is Axios parsing XML in the response data?

Tags: axios

I'm trying to figure out how something is happening: When using Axios on node.js, an HTTP GET that returns an XML body is presented in the response data property already parsed to a JS object. I was surprised by this (and was expecting to get back text that I needed to pass through an XML parser to get a JS object). I could not find any mention of this functionality in the Axios docs, nor could I find a reference to an XML parser in the Axios source code.

Here's a basic example of the Axios code:

```
      let url = `${PB_PID}${values.source}`;
      let result = await http.get(url, {
        timeout: 4000,
        responseType: 'text',
        maxContentLength: 65536
      });
      let data = result.data;  // data is a JS object, parsed from the received XML response
```

I would have expected `data` to contain text. It's not necessarily bad that it automatically parsed the XML, but I want to understand why/how this is happening, for a variety of reasons, including that this may not always be the desired result.

Comment: What's your server ?

Comment: @MichalLevý The Axios client is running on node.js (if that's what you're asking?)

Comment: No, Im asking about the server you are requesting data from ofc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is nothing like "automatic XML parsing" in Axios so only explanation is your server (which you are requesting data from) can handle multiple response formats (response format negotiation) and because you are not sending `Accept: 'application/xml'` header, the default (depends on server implementation) is `application/json` which is indeed automatically parsed by Axios using `JSON.parse()` method

You can check the response-type of the response returned by your server by `console.log(result.headers)`

Comment: Interesting. Well, I'm glad there's no "automatic XML parsing" (because I sure couldn't find it). It is possible (although undocumented) that the target service can return either XML or JSON. I was under the impression that setting `responseType` would also set the `Accept` header, but maybe not?

Comment: Using `responseType` config option **does not** set any request headers.

Comment: Currently I'm using axios v0.21.0 and I can see an unpredictable behaviour I can't rely on: I'm about download a static *.json file (used for localization messages), sending "Accept: application/json" and receiving "Content-Type: application/json". 
But, and that's unwanted, if there is a parsing error, Axios successful and silently resolves with a text string instead of rejecting and complaining about errors. Unpredictable.

Comment: @Plap Yep, that's a [known axios issue](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/61)

Comment: @MichalLevý that's [considered as fixed](https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/3688) BTW

Comment: @gekkedev oh yeah, fixed after 5 years. Maybe Axios is not dead after all :) Thanks for pointing out...